# Rename default "Ubuntu one" folder on 12.04 server possible?

Tags: 12.04, server, ubuntu-one, scripts, tar

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 server from home and using Ubuntu One as backup site. I'm not great at scripts (beginner) so when writing bash scripts that I later crontab for backups, having to use "Ubuntu\ One" or similar methods messes things up. In fact, I had to do in my script "cd 'Ubuntu\ One'" in the script so I could skip using the directory structure in the tar command, cause it wouldn't work.

Any chance to rename the default "Ubuntu One" folder ? or is there some other easy way I'm just not seeing while handling tar commands ?

The following was what I was trying to do, does not work:

```
DEST_DIR="/home/user/Ubuntu\ One/backup"

tar -vczpf ${DEST_DIR}/${FNAME}-${TIMESTAMP}.tar.gz ${SRC_DIR} >> ${LOG}
```

This does work however:

```
cd /home/user/Ubuntu\ One

tar -vczpf ${FNAME}-${TIMESTAMP}.tar.gz ${SRC_DIR} >> ${LOG}
```

I wanted variables so I could backup more specific files and directories and use array later to sort out where stuff goes. Forcing me to "cd" to the U1 directory in the script kinda sucks.

Comment: Quote your variables and the space character won't be a problem. Like "${DEST_DIR}/foo.tar.gz" instead of just ${DEST_DIR}/foo.tar.gz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DEST_DIR="/home/user/Ubuntu One/backup"

tar -vczpf "${DEST_DIR}/${FNAME}-${TIMESTAMP}.tar.gz" ${SRC_DIR} >> ${LOG}
```

The backslash does not escape inside doublequotes. There is no need to escape space bar inside doublequotes however.

Comment: Thanks for a very fast response :D  It had to be something easy as that... I keep learning :)